# Should I use HAVE or HAS in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

> All queues **have** been created.

I thought that "has" was the right choice, but I changed it to "have", because it sounds better. Although I dont know the right choice, so if someone can explain the right choice and why its, I'll be grateful.

Comment: *Have* is correct.  It's correct because "queues" is plural, and the conjugation of "to have" goes *I have, you have, he/she/it has, **they have***.

Comment: Definitely, _have_ is the right choice; ALL is plural.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Have** is the correct choice because "all queues" implies there are multiple queues. Have is the **plural** form of has, and using "has" would not work because it only works for singular nouns, such as

"The queue has been created"